# Kafka on Spark only reads realtime ingestion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, dstream

Spark version = 2.3.0

Kafka version = 1.0.0

Sinppet of code being used:

```
# Kafka Enpoints
zkQuorum = '192.168.2.10:2181,192.168.2.12:2181' 
topic = 'Test_topic'

# Create a kafka Stream
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "cyd-demo-azureactivity-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
```

When the Kafka stream is run real time, I see spark pulling data, however if I start Kafka say an hour before Spark, it will not pick up the hour old data.

Is this expected or is there a way to set something up in a configuration?

Code run using:

```
sudo $SPARK_HOME/spark-submit --master local[2] --jars /home/steven/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.3.2.jar,/home/steven/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.1.jar /home/steven/code/demo/test.py
```

Answer (score 3):

If you always need to pull the data from the start then you need to set the kafka property "`auto.offset.reset`" to "`earliest`". This will pull the records from the start.

This param is Kafka consumer config - http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs

Reference link - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

There are multiple implementations for createStream.. you can use the one in which you can pass the kafka configs.
Sample code for create Stream -

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
"zookeeper.connect" -> "zookeeper1:2181",
"group.id" -> "spark-streaming-test",
"auto.offset.reset" -> "earliet"
)

val inputTopic = "input-topic"

val stream =  KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, kafkaParams, Map(inputTopic-> 1), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Comment: I am using `createStream` not `createDirectStream`, how do I set this parameter then?